# Executing phpunit test in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, codeception

When I run phpunit tests in Laravel using `/vendor/bin/phpunit`
the tests are executed and the results are generated. I am also able to do tests on a single file with `/vendor/bin/phpunit </tests/<filename>`

However, when I execute the following command it fails:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit ./
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Codeception\Module\OrderHelper' not found in
>   /vendor/codeception/codeception/tests/data/claypit/tests/order/ParsedLoadedTest.php
>   on line 2

But I could see that the `OrderHelper` file still exist.

`<project-folder>/vendor/codeception/codeception/tests/data/claypit/tests/_support/OrderHelper.php`

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

The directory passed to phpunit should be the directory where the tests are. So just change it to `./vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

No need to point the directory..
try to do this. it may help you. 
**Bulk File**

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

**Single File**

```
vendor/bin/phpunit <fileName>
```

Comment: Yes, that was working for me. But I am trying to find the issue with the other command.. My client is also getting the same error